# How long will dirty reads stay visible?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

While running the stored procedure CSP1 on AZURE SQL 2012 (Standard: S0) I also ran concurrently

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM [affected_table] WITH (NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Which returns past 10 records in the [affected_table] including those UNCOMMITED by CSP1. When the CSP1 fails and ROLLBACK, no records had been inserted into the `[affected_table]` yet when I re-run the same `SELECT` query with NOLOCK I can still see all those phantom records there.

Shouldn't these be cleared after the ROLLBACK is finished ?

Should I be clearing the cache?

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the sproc?

Comment: The bigger question for me is that if you don't want dirty reads (and the whole host of other awful stuff that happens) why are you using the NOLOCK hint in the first place?

Comment: I admit that I use NOLOCK for speed be aware bad stuff can happen.  You can also get double reads and missed reads.    Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Note: I use NOLOCK (READ UNCOMMITTED) to check on progress of certain interim steps of the procedure CSP1 (the CSP1 can take an awful amount of time to complete depending on the amount of data involved at that hour) which wouldn't be otherwise visible before the COMMIT happens. I do not use it to speed up our processing. I am fully aware of any repercussions if my ISOLATION LEVEL WOULD be actually SET to READ UNCOMMITTED. I just was not aware that the dirty reads would stick around even though CSP1 is long gone finished...

Comment: Again, did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: you mean like FREEPROCCACHE ? ...nope, not yet because I cannot shake off the feeling it will clear ALL the pre-cached stuff and it will slow things down across the whole DB. What is the worst thing that can happen?

Comment: I could not reproduce the described behaviour on my test server. Are you sure that `ROLLBACK` has finished? If it takes long time to insert the rows, it may take long time to roll them back...

Comment: ...strange, I can still reproduce it. Perhaps it is Azure related ?

Answer (score -4):

**Edit**
After some construtive criticsm I fell I diverged from the real question.

1) The dirty reads stays "visible" while the transaction is not commited or rolled back. Note this can take an indefined time and can be hold (bloked) longer by other concurrent transactions.

2) Sure but issuing a rollback or a commit ill not necessary act imediatly. Your (update, insert, delete) transactions issued exclusive locks and the only thing ill prevent dirty reads is using a more restrictive isolation level.

3) You never mess with the cache in production! It's ok in development and even good in some kinds of perfomance tests.

Manage concurrence is an integral part of any DBMS and it's done automaticaly without human intervention (most of time)and  in fact the engine is planned with that in mind.
Of course you can change the isolation level and even try to use hints.

If your requirements needs high concurrence and allows dirty reads be aware you cannot predict how much time they ill be held.
If your cannot allow dirty reads stick with the read commited and never use nolock hint.

### [NOLOCK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

is a common [**Cargo Cult**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) used in TSQL. It was almost mandatory in the past (SQL Server 7) but with the changes in isolation architecture (SQL Server 2000) it become almost obsolete. In fact its considered a bad practice since SQL Server 2005.

If you read the linked MSDN documentation you ill see NOLOCK is the old name for **READUNCOMMITTED** and it **allows dirty reads**.

Some people believe **NOLOCK** magically increases performance and cures deadlocks and balding.

IMHO you can try to get rid of all NOLOCKS.

Note: If you remove a nolock and your system develops a serious case of deadlocks it merely means NOLOCK is maskering another deeper and serious problems. There are scenarios where nolock is recommended but they are rare and needs the attention of a good DBA.

Comment: Where does this answer the question?

Comment: ..sorry man but your answer has nothing to do with my question